# Max value of $a$ given following conditions.

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

In $\Delta$$ABC$, $a$ $\ge$$b$$\ge$$c$. If $$\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{sin^3 A+sin^3 B+ sin^3 C}=7  $$ compute the maximum value of $a$.

**My efforts so far:**

By law of sines i was able to get the following identities:

$a^3=7sin^3A$ , $b^3=7sin^3B$ and $c^3=7sin^3C$

But i don't know how to manipulate these identities in some kind of usefull way, i think i am proceeding in the wrong track.
The problem clearly asks for some tricky manipulation of the equation above,such that applying the restrictions for $a,b,c$ i can not have $a$ greater than some defined value,but ,as i already said, i don't see how to do that.

**Important:** I would really appreciate if you could give me some hints and not the solution right away(maybe you can spoiler it if you want with hints above), otherwise my efforts would've  been vains.

That said,thanks in advance.

---

*(Editing solution in case someone else in the future will need)

**Solution:**

1)Given $a^3=7sin^3A$ ,you have a maximum when $\sin A =1$,hence $a=7^{1/3}$.

2)This problem can also be solved in the following way:
$$\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{sin^3 A+ sin^3 b +sin^3 C} = \frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{\frac{a^3+b^3+c^3}{8R^3}}$$

Solve for R,and then you equate $a=2R$ (a is equal to the diameter of the circumcircle)

Comment: $\frac\pi2\geq a\geq b\geq c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have to make $\sin A$ as large as possible.

Comment: So i have to make $A=\pi/2$ ,which gives me $a=7$ ?

Comment: @Jhon: Almost $\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

HINT (you want not to have an answer): Note that for a right triangle with hypotenuse equal to $a$, your expression equals $a^3$. So for all right triangle with hypotenuse equal to $\sqrt[3] 7$ you have an example satisfying your given expression. What is missing is your job.

Comment: What do you mean by "what is missing is your job"  ?I've worked the problem many times and asked for help at last ...

Comment: I understand that as I stated is not finished but it lacks a little longer to finish.As you want it explicitly.It can be my bad English can be provided to misunderstandings. I'm sorry if this is so. Regards.